# Does every Android screen have the same dpi?

Tags: android

I seem to be very confused after reading the Android Developer [Supporting Multiple Screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html). I thought the dpi was the amount of pixels on each respected screen in order to make the rendered object appear the same on every screen. So, in a way this means dpi is basically a percentage of the screen? For example, if I move an object 10dp in a south bound direction is this basically moving the object a percent of the screen south?

I also thought the dp was a scaled version of pixels to a medium size screen. So does this mean every android device has the same dp screen size?

Some background info:

I am trying to develop a game. In this game objects are falling down the screen. So I would like the objects to appear to be falling and moving around the screen at relatively the same speed on every Android device. Any tips or info to help me get on track or am I way off in my approach?

The current methods I am using for conversions:

```
public static int dpToPx(Context context, float dp) {
    DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
    int px = Math.round(dp * (displayMetrics.densityDpi / DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_DEFAULT));       
    return px;
}

public static int pxToDp(Context context, float px) {
    DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
    int dp = Math.round(px / (displayMetrics.densityDpi / DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_DEFAULT));
    return dp;
}
```

Comment: The answer is in the question: `every android device has the same dp screen size?` **NO, really NOT**. `I seem to be very confused after reading the Android Developer Supporting Multiple Screens.` **YES, you are**

Answer (score 1):

what i would do is get the width and height of the device and than use fractions of that, then it will be the same on all devices

here i got this off of this site maybe it will come in handy for you

```
xlarge screens are at least 960dp x 720dp
large screens are at least 640dp x 480dp
normal screens are at least 470dp x 320dp
small screens are at least 426dp x 320dp
Generalised Dpi values for screens:

ldpi Resources for low-density (ldpi) screens (~120dpi)
mdpi Resources for medium-density (mdpi) screens (~160dpi). (This is the baseline    density.)
hdpi Resources for high-density (hdpi) screens (~240dpi).
xhdpi Resources for extra high-density (xhdpi) screens (~320dpi).

Therefore generalised size of your resources (assuming they are full screen):

ldpi
Vertical = 426 * 120 / 160 = 319.5px
Horizontal = 320 * 120 / 160 = 240px
mdpi
Vertical = 470 * 160 / 160 = 470px
Horizontal = 320 * 160 / 160 = 320px
hdpi
Vertical = 640 * 240 / 160 = 960px
Horizontal = 480 * 240 / 160 = 720px
xhdpi
Vertical = 960 * 320 / 160 = 1920px
Horizontal = 720 * 320 / 160 = 1440px

px = dp*dpi/160
```

Answer (score 1):

[image]

for full information please visit

**http://www.captechconsulting.com/blog/steven-byle/understanding-density-independence-android**